# What is the different between Poisson Nernst–Planck and Poisson Navier–Stokes in the Electrolyte?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology, biophysics, electrochemistry

I am now studying about electroosmosis flow phenomena which is governing by the Navier-Stokes equation and Poisson equation. By combine these two equation we can describe the electrolyte flow velocity field under the influence electric field. But I also found an another equation called Nernst–Planck equation which is describing the flux of ions under the influence of both an ionic concentration gradient and an electric field.

What is the difference Between these two Equation?

[Poisson Nernst–Planck](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=poisson+nernst+planck) vs [Poisson Navier–Stokes](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=poisson+navier+stokes)?

They seems both describing the motion of electrolyte ions under the influence of electric field, but why the equations are so different?